Paired sample (SD and SE)
In some publications, there is no information on whether the data is based on standard deviation (SD) or standard error (SE). For example, in one publication, they wrote: “Mean injection intervals before and after switching were comparable (33.8 ± 11.2 vs. 29.3 ± 2.6 days; p = 0.08).” Usually, the number after ± refers to either SD (standard deviation) or SE (standard error). (forexample in this example: 11.2 refers SD or SE)?

This is impossible to answer in general because it depends on the publication and often even on the authors.  However, you are given enough information to run the test yourself and thereby determine which meaning is intended.  Your example is especially challenging because it looks like the information is inconsistent unless these intervals are based on extremely small sample sizes of perhaps 2 or 3 each.  Is that the case?  Also, what do you mean by "paired sample" in the title?  Perhaps that the test a paired test?  If so, there's no way can determine the answer to your question.

@whuber, thanks for the comment. Yes, I mean paired test.

@whuber, In the following publication, the authors employed paired t.test for comparison. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-024-59632-0

It is not so suprising that some scientists sometimes forget to label the plus minus values. But it is surprising (to me) that this error gets past reviewers and editors. The results cannot be interpreted without knowing what the plus/minus values refer to and what the sample sizes are.
I fooled around with the web calculator at https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ttest2/ and found I could get a p-value of 0.08 when I assumed the plus/minus values were SD and also assumed that the sample size was 21 in each group. But there might possibly be other possible values that work too. Addendum: In fact, as I point out in a comment, the paper makes it reasonably clear the data are paired, so paired t test was probably used.


Just what the OP needs, I think; +1. But a real possibility is that both +/- figures are SEs and this is a paired test--the interpretations are different!

@Harvey Motulsky, thank you so much for your time. However, we are dealing with paired data here, and to run the comparison, we need to enter the observation values. Here is the publication; nature.com/articles/s41598-024-59632-0. As can be seen, they do not clearly mention whether the values after ± refer to either SD (standard deviation) or SE (standard error).

I read the paper, and indeed it seems to be a paired design, so a paired t-test would have been appropriate. No way to know what they did.

By the way, the instructions for authors for Nature: Scientific Reports are pretty good regarding statistics.
https://arc.net/l/quote/pmqslfap
"You must state whether a number that follows the ± sign is a standard error (s.e.m.) or a standard deviation (s.d.)."

@Harvey Motulsky, great, thank you so much for your time
